# Samba 4.11 and des-cbc-md5

Tags: kerberos, samba4

Although noted as an weak encryption type, I want to know how to enable des-cbc-md5 on Samba 4.11, in [this doc](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Security_Documentation) is stated:

> des-cbc-md5 (disabled by default)
>
> des-cbc-md5 can be enabled by enabling DES at a user-level, but this is generally not considered secure, which is why it is disabled by default. "

What does it mean "at user level"?
I have tried to edit the file `/var/lib/samba/private/kdc.conf`, but if des-md5-cbc is included in the supported enctypes line, samba won't restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Fedora for security reasons, in the latest release of samba(4.10,4.11) apply a patch to remove completely the insicure des encryption
Even the latest release of kerberos(1.18) has removed this encryption, and now the patch seems to be in the tree of the latest samba sources(4.12rc)