# Samba 4.15 DES-DBC-MD5

Tags: samba, samba4

Is there a way to enable des-cbc-md5 ? I have opensuse Leap 15.3 and samba 4.15 and I need to accept Windows XP and Windows 7 clients.
I read [Samba 4.11 and des-cbc-md5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555000/samba-4-11-and-des-cbc-md5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Open "gpedit.msc".

Go in:
Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options.

In the right pane, look for the option "Network security: Configure allowed encryption types for Kerberos".

Check the DES_CBC_CRC and DES_CBC_MD5 options.

After that, restart your PC.

When you apply this setting, you will be able to authenticate and access file shares. You will not be able to gpupdate or access Active Directory Users and Computers because of the DES change. Windows will also repeatedly prompt you to lock your computer and re-enter your new credentials despite being logged in with your current credentials.

In this case, these cons have to be taken into account. It's a workaround but your users will be able to authenticate via the network and work with files.

Kind regards,

Felipe Omega.